# Apply same function to multiple links. Show/Hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, toggle

When of the links below are click I need the to take place when user clicks in on various buttons. see test site here: http://tryoutyourwebsite.com/sand

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#teams').animate({
      marginTop: '-495px'
  }, 200);

  $('.trigger').toggle(function(){

          $('#teams').animate({
              marginTop: '0'
          }, 500);

      },
      function(){
          $('#teams').animate({
              marginTop: '-495px'
          }, 500);
  });
});


<div id="close-teams" class="trigger"><a href="#"><img src="images/up-arrow.png"></a></div>    
<li><div id="open" class="trigger"><a href="#">Teams</a></div></li>
<div id="turtle" class="trigger"><a href="#teams">vote for a team</a></div>
```

Comment: You need the *what* to take place?

Comment: if I understood correctly, when user clicks one of the team boxes from the expanded div, you want this div to hide?

Comment: Please, explain clearly. You might have use tags in your text. Remove them.

Comment: If they click "teams" in the orange nav area, I want them to be able to click the arrow icon to close the top blue area that dropped down. The problem I'm having is they have to click the arrow twice instead of once.

Comment: Just so you're aware, the `.toggle(function,function)` method [has been removed as of jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). It seems that you're using 1.8.2 on that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are two elements with class `.trigger`, each remembers its own state if its toggled or not.

You can write separate functions for clicking menu item and arrow or check if the `#teams div hidden` or not in trigger click:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    if($('#teams').css('marginTop') == "0px") {
        $('#teams').animate({
            marginTop: '-495px'
        }, 500);              
    } else {
        $('#teams').animate({
            marginTop: '0px'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is right. The only problem is I need the top blue area to be hidden when the page loads and show the menu is clicked. This seems to be reversed. Is there any easy way to reverse this?

Comment: try adding style to #teams, for example in css #teams {margin: -495px 0 0 0; }